# Electric/smart parentheses: allow wrapping in a nontransient way

Tags: balanced-parentheses, smartparens, electric-pair-mode

I like smart parentheses as much as the next person, but there is one situation in which I often get frustrated.  Suppose I have a TeX line reading:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Now I wish to `\emph`asize `dolor`.  Hence I go before it and write `\emph{`, resulting, with `electric-pair-mode` and the likes, in:

```
Lorem ipsum \emph{}|dolor sit amet
```

(where | is the point).
Now the behavior I'd like to have, is that if I only thereafter *move* then insert `}`, then the automagically inserted `}` is removed.  Graphically, I'd like to end up with:

```
Lorem ipsum \emph{dolor}| sit amet
```

rather than:

```
Lorem ipsum \emph{}dolor}| sit amet
```

**Question:** Is there a mode that implements that behavior?  Note that I *don't* want to use the transient mark.

Comment: Consider not bothering with "smartparens" or "electric-pair", if you haven't already. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I spent the last 15 years happily emacs'ing without any smartness in my parentheses, so I certainly understand the suggestion.  As a matter of fact, I'm mostly *testing out* electricity here; not sure I'll adopt it, especially if I cannot get the above question worked out.  Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: Lots of people **do** like such "smart"/"electric" pairing. Some others (maybe mostly oldtimers?) do not. (To me, they're more of a bother than a help.) Hope you get an answer that helps.

Comment: There is a specialized list for these modes: auctex@gnu.org

Comment: Why don't you want to use transient mark? That is the most direct solution: mark `dolor`, then `C-c C-f C-e` will wrap it with `\emph{}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve that specific effect, but I often do something very similar that works with both smartparens and post-24.4 electric-pair.

In this case, I would type \emph, set the visible mark, move the point after dolor, and *then* press { or }.  This will cause the electric mode in question to bracket the marked region.

In other words, set the following line up so that the italics represent the marked region, then press an electric paren key like {:

Lorem ipsum \emph*dolor* sit amet

My personal habit is to press { if I'm at the beginning of a marked region and } if I'm at the end, but it seems to work either way.

Comment: BTW, you can mark the word with `C-M-SPC`.

Comment: Sure!  However you would normally mark the relevant region.  It has to be marked, though, the OP wanted something more automagical, I think.